# GWT + Serialization

Tags: gwt, serialization, subclass

I am having hard time trying to serialize my class (literally 3-4 hour to find a solutio). I add a subclass to an existing serializable and functioning class, and than get the following error message:

```
 [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DelegatingChangeListenerCollection is not default instantiable (it must have a zero-argument constructor or no constructors at all) and has no custom serializer. (reached via com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc)
              [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DelegatingClickListenerCollection is not default instantiable (it must have a zero-argument constructor or no constructors at all) and has no custom serializer. (reached via com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc)
              [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DelegatingFocusListenerCollection is not default instantiable (it must have a zero-argument constructor or no constructors at all) and has no custom serializer. (reached via com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc)
              [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DelegatingKeyboardListenerCollection is not default instantiable (it must have a zero-argument constructor or no constructors at all) and has no custom serializer. (reached via com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc)
              [ERROR] com.google.gwt.view.client.ListDataProvider<T>.ListWrapper<> is not default instantiable (it must have a zero-argument constructor or no constructors at all) and has no custom serializer. (reached via com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc)
              [ERROR] com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc.LogCollection is not default instantiable (it must have a zero-argument constructor or no constructors at all) and has no custom serializer. (reached via com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc)
              [ERROR] com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc.LogCollection has no available instantiable subtypes. (reached via com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc)
                 [ERROR]    subtype com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc.LogCollection is not default instantiable (it must have a zero-argument constructor or no constructors at all) and has no custom serializer. (reached via com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc)
              [ERROR] java.util.AbstractList.SubList<E> is not default instantiable (it must have a zero-argument constructor or no constructors at all) and has no custom serializer. (reached via com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc)
              [ERROR] java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableList<T> is not default instantiable (it must have a zero-argument constructor or no constructors at all) and has no custom serializer. (reached via com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc)
              [ERROR] java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableRandomAccessList<T> is not default instantiable (it must have a zero-argument
```

My class looks like:

```
public class ItemRecRpc implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5828108890651522661L;
        .
        .

        private String rId;
    private LogCollection logColl;//if i comment this, no error message...

    public class LogCollection{ 

        public LogCollection(){

        }
        //public long creationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //public LongVector times = new LongVector();
        //public ArrayList<Object> messages = new ArrayList<Object>();
        //public int nSkipped = 0; 
        //public int nExceptions = 0; 
        //public Exception firstException = null; 
        //public long endGcTime=0;
        public long endTime;
    }
.
.
.
}
```

When i comment the "private LogCollection logColl" line it is ok, but when i uncomment i again get the error mesage. I tried with static keyword, as you see i comment every subclass variable, but can not help... Anyway if i create a new class:

```
public class LogCollectionRpc implements Serializable {

    public LogCollectionRpc() {
        //
    }
    public long creationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    public LongVector times = new LongVector();
    public ArrayList<Object> messages = new ArrayList<Object>();
    public int nSkipped = 0; // due to reaching the limit
    public int nExceptions = 0; // due to MyAppender-s
    public Exception firstException = null; // due to MyAppender-s
    public long endGcTime = 0;
    public long endTime;

}
```

And than try to use this as my functioning class, it is ok... But this thing is really bugging my mind...

Any idea? Gwt dont support subclass serialization? Or am i miss something. Aprreciate any answer.

Best Regards,
Peter

Comment: It's what @jusio says: inner not static classes need an enclosing instance, so their constructor receives an extra argument (when compiled). That's why it's complaining about not having a zero-arg constructor. In this case the most appropiate I think is declare LogCollection as `public static class` to make it unrelated to the enclosing type. Or directly move it to a new file of its own. The reason why removing the `private LogCollection...` field works is that GWT realizes it doesn't need the subtype and ignores it.

Comment: true, but as it seems it is also make compailing but if i write "implements Serializable" GWT not complaining anymore, so static and implements also essential to not complain. Weird isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error:

`subtype com.client.rpc.ItemRecRpc.LogCollection is not default instantiable`

Says that it can't create and instance of `LogCollection` by default. And it is true. Because to create an instance of `LogCollection`, you first need to have an instance of `ItemRecRpc`. Declaring `LogCollection` as static class should have helped.

Basically, when you want to send some object over gwt-rpc, all the classes used as fields in such object should be  instantiable by default. (e.g. no special tricks to create it, just new and empty constructor). Also you can define a custom field serializer for any class, which can be instantiated by default.

Comment: perfect answer, thanks for it. It is solved my problem. (i tried with static, but there were so much project, not build the proper one:/ facepalm:( but now as you told me, i concentrate and rebuild proper projects and it is good!)

Comment: ok testing, it, and last comment was fail:( still has the same message, really weird, maybe it is seriulsy a GWT issue... and you cannnot make a subclass in any class implements seriazable... I am  trying to get over with this bug...

"public static class LogCollection"

Comment: Ok. Maybe it has a solution:

"public static class LogCollection implements Serializable"

Not only need to be static, but need to implements Seriazable aswell... The really weird thing in this, as i know subclass of a Serializable class implements also Serializable (without to add explicit), but not in GWT as i see... Really weird... But in this was, with static, and implements keywords there is no error message...

Comment: @czupe `LogCollection` is not sublcass of `ItemRecRpc` . It is an `inner` class, totally different thing.

Comment: true, sorry for miss the expressions (subclass vs innerclass) , now it is ok, why need to write explicitly "implement Serializable"